# Find the expected value of Y=min(X,M), where X is exponential with θ=2 and M is a constant.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I tried by expressing  Y= $\frac{X+M-|X-M|}{2}$.

So:

$$E[Y] = \frac{1}{2}( E[X] + E[M] + E[|X-M|] )$$

But I'm stuck with E[|X-M|].

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Condition $Y$ on whether $X$ is less or greater than $M$:

$E[Y]=E[Y|X\leq M]P(X\leq M)+E[Y|X>M]P(X>M)$

In other words:

$E[Y]=\int_{x=0}^M xf_X(x)dx+M\int_{x=M}^\infty f_X(x)dx$

Comment: You know you can use \le for $\le$...

Comment: yes... corrected

Comment: Why condition and uncondition? For every function $u$, $$E(u(X))=\int u(x)f_X(x)dx$$ Use this for $$u(x)=\min(x,M)$$

Comment: That's right. It gets to the same formula. Upvoted.